# angular - ng-if - how to callback after ng-if template has been rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

in Angular, I need to call a function after an element with certain class has been loaded.
Display of the element is controlled via ng-if='expr'. Value of $scope.expr is set after some ajax call has responded.

Now, if I try putting $watch on expr, or using $evalAsync. it is not working. probably the reason being that these events are run before the template part actually runs.

Here is a sample code : http://jsbin.com/kuyas/1/edit
Here I need a callback sort of thing on ng-if that gets executed after the template has rendered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem was that there is no way to know if angular is done with the digest loop, ensuring that all elements have been rendered.

To solve this issue, there were two options

1. Wrap your callback function in a directive. include that directive in ng-if. and make that expression true only when u want your callback to be executed.
2. Call your callback function inside, `setTimeOut(function(){ ... }, 0);` as browsers by default keep all events in a queue, therefore, when digest loop is running, your callback function will enter the queue and get executed as soon digest loop is over.

Comment: I prefer this solution with setTimeout, allowing me to do things that are not a widget on a page or restricted to being inside the ng_if

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){
  // do whatever
}, 0);`

This is perfect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

One possible answer would be to create a directive that does whatever you want to do. If you then use that directive only within the section of HTML controlled by the ng-if, then the directive will be dormant until the ng-if expression is true.

Would that do what you want?

Comment: I love this. I created a IAmRendered component which will respond on $OnInit() for being rendered and on $OnDestroy() for its funeral! Great suggestion.

Comment: @Mattijs, How do we do this in angular1

Comment: @SukeshChand Check my answer below

Answer (score 6):

Simplest solution in my view is to do the following:

```
<div ng-if="sectionActivated">
    <div ng-init="callBack()"></div>
</div>
```

Your callback will be called only when what is affected by `ng-if` has been rendered.

Comment: this partially worked for me, but have used `setTimeout(function(){ // do whatever }, 0);` also because there were some custom elements which were not yet ready as i was trying to disable them, so for those custom elements I used set timeout after 5 seconds of page loading to disable them

Answer (score 1):

The directive could look something like this:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

class OnFinishRenderDirective implements angular.IDirective {

  public restrict = 'A';
  public replace = false;

  public link = (
    scope: any,
    // scope:        angular.IScope,
    element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery,
    attr: any,
    modelCtrl: any,
    link: angular.ITemplateLinkingFunction ) => {

    if ( scope.$last === true ) {
      this.$timeout(() => {
        scope.$emit( 'elementRendered' );
      } );
    }

  }

  constructor( private $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService ) { }

}

export function onFinishRenderFactory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {

  var directive = ( $timeout: angular.ITimeoutService ) => new OnFinishRenderDirective( $timeout );
  directive.$inject = [ '$timeout' ];
  return directive;
}
```

You would have to import it and add to your module

```
import { onFinishRenderFactory } from './onFinishRender/onFinishRender.directive';

angular.module( 'yourModule', [] )
.directive( 'onFinishRender', onFinishRenderFactory() )
```

Then you can use the directive somewhere in your markup to emit the event when the directive has been rendered.

```
<div onFinishRender>I am rendered</div>
```

You could even add an extra attribute in the directive DIV which you can then grab from the ATTR object in the link function and add to your $emit function to identify this specific DIV to be rendered.

Does that answer your question?